# Query Multi-location in MongoDB using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, geospatial

I'm trying to query a document using spatial indexes.

According to [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#multi-location-documents) my model looks like:

```
class Trip
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :addresses, :type => Array
  index({"addresses.loc" => "2d"}, {:min => -180, :max => 180})
end
```

Addesses are stored like this

```
Trip.first.addresses
=> [{"context"=>"from", "loc"=>[-71.55234, -33.024527]}, {"context"=>"to", "loc"=>[-70.641997, -33.4691199]}]
```

I would like to query documents that match address.loc and address.context using this query:

```
Trip.where("addresses.loc" => {"$nearSphere" => [-70.641997, -33.4691199], "$maxDistance" => 0.005052092295133236}).where("addresses.context" => "to")
```

The query returns proper values but it seems to be ignoring the "address.context".
I'm I doing it the proper way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In order to find documents with arrays that match an expression you should use #elem_match:

```
Trip.elem_match(addresses: {context: 'to', _rest_of_your_geospatial_stuff_ })
```

Read more here:

http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html

Comment: BTW why not make separate fields for 'from' and 'to' locations and make things simpler?

Comment: because of [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#multi-location-documents) **"2d indexes do not support more than one set of coordinates in a document"**

Comment: Fair point. But: "New in version 2.0: Support for multiple locations in a document."

Comment: Yes, but you can't specify to search into a particular context, right ?

Comment: I don't know. Please let me know if #elem_match solved your problem.

Comment: not really. I need to use 2 snkpetial indexes for my query I Think.
elem_match any of points, [from or to].
Thx anyway